# Grub rescuse revovery?

Tags: 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it was working fine two nights ago and now all day today it has shown me this:

Error:unknown filesystem
grub rescue>

I know how to recover from this, but are all my files gone because of this? Please help.